# Nodejs HTTP server connect memcache

Tags: node.js

I build a http server using nodejs. Each request income, http server connect to memcache, check and return data or do something else. When I use Apache Benchmark to test perfomance like : -n 1000. The output show it has just completed about 900 requests, then http server can't serve anymore. 
What am I doing wrong? Can you explain what happens?

here my code :

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var client = new mc.Client(ip, mc.Adapter.binary);
    client.connect(function() {
    client.get(key, function(err, response) {
    if(err) { //not exist
        ..
        res.end(result)
    ..
    }
    else {  //exist in memcache
        var result = response[key];   
        res.end(result);
    }
});
```

});
});
here is result after benchmarch:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.4.1 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 896 requests completed
```

Update : I figured out I didn't disconnect memcached each request. Problem resolved !!!

Comment: I think your if-else logic is incorrect. Error does not mean key not exists. I believe nil is returned when key does not exist. Error is for failure in processing the command given.

Comment: Yeah i know , but when i'm using mc module and key not exist it printed error and response is null, too. And if can't connect memcache I don't find any api in mc modul like timeout .. so I have to start memcache first .

Answer (score 0):

One tricky thing about nodejs application is that there is a memory cap of 1.4GB. If your server uses more than the allowed limit it will hang or crash. You can custom build your nodejs application to increase this value.

Make sure that you garbage collect your varibles if not used (like setting some module scope varibles to null).

I dont have enough information to tell you what went wrong. I would suggest looking at server logs.

Comment: i updated my code. I don't think it's out of memory , it seem server can't get data from memcache anymore ..